# Math for virtual grab arm

Tags: geometry

So I have this kind of grab arm. It consists of 2 parts ***A*** and ***B*** (know length), that can change it's angle at start point and between A and B. I need to calculate the angles (necessary rotations), so the arm (B ending) grabs the goal (position is know). As for 2D I figured that it forms a triangle and as I know all 3 side lengths, I can easily calculate the needed angles. However when it comes to 3D my head explodes and I can't think of any strategy. So any help appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the distance between the goal and centre is less than $A + B$, then join centre to goal and consider only the plane defined by the triangle formed by sides $A, B, C$, which is same as the $2D$ case.

There are many different solutions (eg. any rotation of the triangle around length $C$)

Comment: A solution, that mimic natural human arm movement would be preferable.